# ElasticSearch Field Type "date" inserting date('Y-m-d H:i:s')

Tags: date, datetime, indexing, elasticsearch, kibana

I´m trying to insert a datetime value into my Es index. But i don´t understand it right at the moment.

If I do a custom mapping with e.g. "eventDate" => "date" and try to index a doc with "eventDate" => date('Y-m-d H:i:s') i get this error:

IllegalArgumentException[Invalid format: \"2014-03-13 15:36:15\" is malformed at \" 15:36:15\"]; ","status":400}

I understand that, but I don´t know what i should change ?!?! I wanna use that field in Kibana histogram later on, so it must be a date field.

In Es docs I saw the date-format like this: "Y-m-dTH:i:s" !
What does this "T" in the middle ?? And how can I index this exactly like this ?

Thanks für your help.
marc

Answer (score 1):

The `T` is simply a delimiter of the date. You can read more information about this in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations):

> A single point in time can be represented by concatenating a complete date expression, the letter T as a delimiter, and a valid time expression. For example "2007-04-05T14:30".
>   If a time zone designator is required, it follows the combined date and time. For example "2007-04-05T14:30Z" or "2007-04-05T12:30-02:00".
>
> Either basic or extended formats may be used, but both date and time must use the same format. The date expression may be calendar, week, or ordinal, and must use a complete representation. The time expression may use reduced accuracy. It is permitted to omit the 'T' character by mutual agreement.

And for the indexing error, try to put the `T` delimiter and also the timezone (you can just put `Z`, that means `UTC`). After that you should be able to plot graphs in Kibana.